# Is American citizenship automatic when born on US soil?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, citizenship

The US constitution states that

> All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to
>   the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States and the
>   State wherein they reside.

Does this mean that anyone who is born in the US is automatically a US citizen, whether they want it or not? Or does this amendment just offer the possibility of requesting citizenship?

In other words: is there an action to be made in order to become a US citizen when born in the US (and therefore one is not before this action is performed)?

Note: this question is different from [another one](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/33056/what-is-the-meaning-of-and-subject-to-the-jurisdiction-thereof-in-the-14th-ame) which deals with the "*and subject to the jurisdiction thereof*" part. Mine is about the automatism (or lack of) of the acquisition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of “and subject to the jurisdiction thereof” in the 14th amendment?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/33056/what-is-the-meaning-of-and-subject-to-the-jurisdiction-thereof-in-the-14th-ame)

Comment: @DavidSiegel I would distinguish this question from the other because this one asks not about the meaning of the jurisdiction clause but about whether citizenship must be asserted by some affirmative act.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: I updated my question - it is not a duplicate indeed.

Comment: I have retracted my vote to close as a duplicate

Comment: A baby does not understand what citizenship is, so "whether they want it or not" is meaningless.

Comment: @Nacht: it is not meaningless at all. Having American citizenship has tremendous impacts in the way you handle taxes abroad. Someone born "by chance" in the US without any intent of having the citizenship is then in trouble (especially that it looks like they have to wait before being able to renounce it). This is different from *jus sanguinis* cases where there is obviously no chance involved (in how the citizenship is transferred)

Comment: Maybe this is another question, but couldn't you just fly back to your home country and just never mention the baby was a US citizen?  Who would know?  Who would care?

Comment: @JPhi1618 in most countries, the child will need a birth certificate or other registration, and for international travel, the child will need a passport.  Both of these will normally list the place of birth.

Comment: @WoJ I think Nacht's comment was that there is no way a newborn could want or not want citizenship.  The capacity to form an opinion on the question will not develop until several years after the birth.

Comment: Ah, @WoJ by your contrasting with *jus sanguinis*, I suppose you meant whether the *parents* wanted the child to have citizenship or not, rather than the baby. That is a fair point.

Comment: @JPhi1618: The US administration would know. At his/her next travel to the US as a taxpayer they would be in trouble for not having payed their taxes in the US (no matter where they live). Also the US will be able to demand extradition of their "citizen" from a third party country (this is an extreme case but still)

Comment: @phoog: yes, I understand that. Having children, the "several years" can be many severals :) In any case I was thinking about the consequences of a birth on US soil + the lack of will (for the parents) to have the nationality. All is clear now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Does this mean that anyone who is born in the US is automatically a US citizen, whether they want it or not?

Yes (subject to a couple of exceptions, namely the children of diplomats with full immunity and the children of a hostile foreign occupier).

> Or does this amendment just offer the possibility of requesting citizenship?  In other words: is there an action to be made in order to become a US citizen when born in the US (and therefore one is not before this action is performed)?

No.  For someone who falls under the 14th amendment's citizenship clause, the only way to avoid being a US citizen is to [relinquish or renounce it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relinquishment_of_United_States_nationality), which generally means that one is stuck with the US citizenship for at least 18 years.

Most countries' citizenship laws, or at least all of those with which I am familiar, operate this way—automatically—for "normal" cases of acquisition of citizenship by virtue of the circumstances of birth.  This is true whether the citizenship derives from the place of birth or from the parents' citizenship.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99264/discussion-on-answer-by-phoog-is-american-citizenship-automatic-when-born-on-us).

Answer (score 5):

If you're assuming that the child is "subject to the jurisdiction thereof," the child is a citizen of the United States, immediately upon birth.

No waiting, no paperwork, no red tape.

Comment: But taxes, no matter where you live, and no citizenship renouncement before paying all of it. (This may well apply to a minor with income of some sort.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider most US citizens living abroad pay no tax, benefiting as they do from the foreign tax credit or the foreign earned income exclusion.

Comment: @phoog But you still have to file.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider indeed, and that can be burdensome and costly.